# Is there any project in existence to have common (all apps) settings?

Tags: software-recommendation, settings

Is there any project in existence that shall bring all the settings of all apps under one window.

Somewhat like what exists in *iOS*.Something like this -

[image]

Also,is there any such thing in existence that shall make apps compulsory to have settings...atleast minimal.

And then these settings be combined in one single settings app.May be an **App settings** included in our normal Systems Settings window..

If there is no such project in existence,I would like to suggest this feature for Ubuntu.!

Thankyou :)

A community answer would be nice!

Comment: No there is not. However most gtk-based apps will store their configuration information in either GConf or GSettings/DConf so in some sense it is possible that this might eventually come to be.

Comment: Personally I don't think this would be desirable on a Desktop OS...

Comment: @fluteflute..why not? it would be easier to have access to settings and also,the interface of settings would be more consistent..like for e.g as of now,some apps may provide to increase or decrease a value using a slider and some with an up-down counter...whereas in this common settings thing,the interface can be made common for all to have sliders!..imo :)

Comment: Of course, don't forget that there are programs like `dconf-editor` which present you a list with values of some programs

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely no application like that and there never will be. In iOS we have one system (iOS) from one company (apple) so every developer for iOS has to integrate his/her app into this system, but for GNU/Linux systems like Ubuntu, things aren't the same.

In addition I have to say that less than half of the iOS-Apps are integrated in the iOS settings menu.